# Which universities in the U.S. are doing research in type theory?

Tags: soft-question, type-theory

The question is meant to be broad in that recommendations with mentions of the particular areas within type theory research are greatly appreciated. Also, the research need not be conducted in computer science departments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean Martin-Löf (dependent) Type Theory, or type systems in general, or uses of dependent type theory for program verification? Because those are related but pretty different areas, and the first (type theory in the strict sense) seems much smaller in the US, and much more European... Off the top of my head, Stephanie Weirich, Aaron Stump, and the Constable group count for type theory, and maybe Brigitte Pientka. Program verification using Coq is a much larger area.

Comment: @Blaisorblade All the people you mentioned are doing the kind of research I had in mind (I see the phrase "computational logic" used, maybe that helps). But I am also interested in schools that do research in MLTT...so I guess in every sense. I became aware of this research as a math person learning about HoTT. In doing that, I've gotten the sense that there is more general research in type theories, semantics of type theories, its connection to classical/ non-classical logic and category theory. I want to know more about this type of stuff and where its done. I hope that helps explain.

Comment: Carnegie Mellon University. In the School of Computer Science you have the PL group (Robert Harper, Frank Pfenning, Karl Crary, and others). In the Philosophy Department you have got Steven Awodey. This may be the largest US concentration of type theory. Mike Shulman is in San Diego.

Comment: Is this a candidate for a big-list of answers/ community wiki? There seem to be several places at least.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Any such list is always subjective, but the best approach to answer this question is:

1. Look at journals/conferences in the area you're interested in. For type theory, I'd look at [LICS](https://dl.acm.org/conference/lics), [LMCS](https://lmcs.episciences.org/), [POPL](https://dl.acm.org/conference/popl), [ICFP](https://dl.acm.org/conference/icfp), and [JFP](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-functional-programming).
2. Find papers that seem interesting, or are in the area you're interested in.
3. Look at the schools the authors are from.

There's another important underlying point here, which is the *for graduate studies, the school matters much less than the supervisor*. So you're far better off looking for the research you're interested in, and then trying to work with the people conducting it, then to choose a school first and then try to find a supervisor and area.